# How to configure domain or IP Address in Angular + Spring Boot

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot

I have an Angular 11 application in the public folder of a Spring project.
Spring project is running on port 8075, if I access my aplication from localhost:8075 everything works fine.
If I access from another machine using the ip address from where spring is running, the page is loaded but every call from Angular to spring rest api fails because the addess in agular in every call goes to localhost.
How can I configure the url of api calls in Angular to reach spring rest from any client that can resolve than ip? In other words, if the server is running in 10.0.0.1 and from a client 10.0.0.2 enter http://10.0.0.1:8075 angular calls go to 10.0.0.1:8075 and not localhost

IE:

```
private urlEndPoint: string = 'http://localhost:8075/api/categorias';
private httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({'Content-type': 'application/json'})¨

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

getCategorias(): Observable<Categoria[]>{
    return this.http.get<Categoria[]>(this.urlEndPoint);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: For that you should use Angular environment configuration where you will put the API url instead of hardcoding it like this. https://angular.io/guide/build

Answer (score 0):

> Use angular configuration. When you host the spring backend, you have
> to change only the baseUrl in the environment files

environment.prod.ts (this is used to production server)

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://10.0.0.1:8075/api/',
};
```

environment.ts (this is used to development server)

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  baseUrl: 'http://10.0.0.1:8075/api/'
};
```

In service.ts import

```
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';
```

then method `getCategorias()` should be

```
getCategorias(): Observable<Categoria[]>{
    return this.http.get<Categoria[]>(environment.baseUrl+"categorias");
}
```